# How to remove already scheduled LocalNotifications in an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

I am using Local Notifications. I want to delete already scheduled notifications.I don't know where to write the code.Here is my code ..

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate =  self.selectedDate;
    NSLog(@" self.selectedDate %@", self.selectedDate);
    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    NSLog(@"itemDate %@",itemDate);
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
      NSLog(@"itemDate %@", localNotif.fireDate);
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [_titleTextFieldObj text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    NSLog(@" localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber ++ %ld", (long)localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber );



    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[_titleTextFieldObj text] forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
    NSArray *notificationArray = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    //UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"notif %@",notificationArray);

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Here I'm writing the removing of notification....

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
        NSLog(@"userInfoCurrent %@",userInfoCurrent);
        NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
        NSLog(@"uid %@",uid);
        if ([uid isEqualToString:[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"]])
        {
            //Cancelling local notification
            [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"notify %@",notification);
        NSString *custom=[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"];
         NSLog(@"custom %@",custom);
         NSString *newString = [custom stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

         NSLog(@"newString %@",newString);

        NSLog(@"custmky%@",notification.description);
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:newString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        alert.delegate=self;
        [alert show];


    }


}
```

I am new to UILocalNotifications and Objective-c. Can anyone please help me ....

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel a UILocationNotification either by comparing fire dates to already scheduled UILocalNotifications or using its body.
An example of canceling by fire date:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSDate *dateToCancel = nil; // Set this to the date you want to cancel
for (UILocalNotification *notification in [application scheduledLocalNotifications])
{
    if (notification.fireDate == dateToCancel)
    {
        [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
```

Now if you have a notification pointer you can just call the cancel local notification without needing to loop through already scheduled notifications. If you want you can also add an Id tag to the notification through key-object methods.

Answer (score 0):

No matter in which class that code will lay, it's anywhere using UIApplication singleton...
You can cancel all notification using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

If you want to remove a particular notification, you can use userinfo of notification object, when you create a local notification add a unique ID to that. Later you can use that ID for removing local notification.

For that you can use the following code:

```
NSString *notificationId = @"id_to_cancel";
UILocalNotification *notification = nil;
for(UILocalNotification *notify in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])
{
  if([notify.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:notificationId ])
  {
     notification = notify;
     break;
  }
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
```

Comment: it is crashing.The error is " attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'".

Comment: It's because you need to create local notifications also with ID.